# What is the difference between CPU Threads and threads created through programming?

Tags: multithreading, cpu

In my CPU I know I have 8 cores and 16 threads (2 threads by core).

But when I create threads through programming (for example in c++) I can create more than 100,000 threads.

Then what's the difference between those two kinds of threads?

Comment: Your CPU can task switch so that your 100,000 logical threads run in 16 actual CPU threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A C++ thread is just a sequence of instructions and your native thread(cpu thread) is something which can run a C++ thread.

- **C++ thread**: something to run
- **Hardware thread**: where it can run